# Extract month and year from date in oracle ORA-01722: Nombre non valide

Tags: oracle, plsql

So i'm trying to extract the month and the year from a date for exemple : 01/07/2018 will return 'JUL-18'

I'm trying this simple query to try the extraction

```
select TO_CHAR('01/10/2008','MON-YY') from dual
```

But it returns the following exception

> ORA-01722: Nombre non valide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'01/10/2008'` is a string, not a date. There are four `to_char()` functions which take different argument types, and (presumably because of implicit [conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-6DB331B5-0F34-4215-9A20-16AEA9D7FF4B) precedence) you're actually ending up calling [`to_char(number)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html), not the `(date)` version you intended.

That means you're effectively doing `TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER('01/10/2008'), 'MON-YY')`, and it's the implicit `TO_NUMBER('01/10/2008')` that is throwing the ORA-01722.

If you are starting with that string and you're trying to effectively change the format then you need to explicitly convert to a date first, then convert back to a string:

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/10/2008', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MON-YY') from dual;

TO_CHA
------
OCT-08
```

As the month names and abbreviations are dependent on NLS settings, you might want to override the session settings to get a consistent result:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='FRENCH';

select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MON-YY') from dual;

TO_CHAR(
--------
JUIL.-18

select TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/07/2018', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MON-YY',
  'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') from dual;

TO_CHA
------
JUL-18
```

Answer (score 3):

You need two steps here.  First, use `TO_DATE` to convert the text date into a bona fide date, and then call `TO_CHAR` to format it the way you want:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('01/10/2008', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MON-YY')
FROM dual;

OCT-08
```

### Demo

Note: It would be better to just work with valid Oracle date literals if possible.  For example, the following query avoids the call to `TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE '2008-10-01', 'MON-YY')
FROM dual;
```